# What is the best way to limit an ansible install task to only install if the package is not already present

Tags: ansible

While creating a playbook for a vagrant box, I want to skip install steps if the package is already installed. This seems like such a common scenario but is not expliclity mentioned in the [conditional docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) as far as I can tell.

I am running a playbook multiple times during testing and want to install packages conditionally so I don't have to keep running tasks which I know are working e.g.

```
- name: Install useful packages
  yum: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - "@development-tools"
    - git
    - curl
    - htop
```

How would I add a conditional here which only installs the above packages if they are not already installed? Is there another state I can use or do I need to manually run something in the shell which checks if they are installed first? e.g. something using `yum list installed <packagename>` or `yum info <packagename>`. I would rather not have to create a task for each package as this will become unwieldy when there are lots of packages to install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible is idempotent. You can run yum module as many times as you want. If there is nothing to install that task will end with changed=false status and packages will not be re-installed.

Comment: Had I not experienced the exact opposite when re-running a playbook, I would not have asked the question.

Comment: @codecowboy What you describe is _not_ expected behavior, and this answer is generally correct. You should edit your question to describe in more detail what is going on.

Comment: @codecowboy show logging (preferably with `-vvvv`) that shows already-installed packages attempt to be reinstalled.

Comment: Seems I was mistaken. One task was taking an unusually long time but the logging showed that it was being skipped. There is something else causing the performace hit but I dont have time to investigate further. Thanks for your answers and comments